# Parse redirection URL

Tags: regex, python-3.x, url, beautifulsoup, phishing

I analyze the URL in a malicious e-mail. I parse the e-mail using BeautifulSoup. I get this URL

https://www.google.com/url?q=http://my.%42%41%44%2e%43%4F&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNGTKogvWUF40RsyeAXrGi6uQrlhoQ

This URL will force Google.com to redirect to http://my.BAD.CO Given a URL like the one above how can I know that the URL will trigger redirect?

I want to get an indication that this is a redirect and I want to get two separate URLs
http://my.BAD.CO and https://www.google.com/url?q=http://5sr0s.%61%6b%68%6f%72%61%62%2e%72%75&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNGTKogvWUF40RsyeAXrGi6uQrlhoQ

where http://my.BAD.CO is an encoded target URL http://my.%42%41%44%2e%43%4F

If the only solution is a custom RegEx like this

```
(?i)(http|https)://(www.|)google.com/url\?q=(http|https)://(\S+)\&usg=\S+
```

followed by a call to *urllib.parse.unquote* will it cover all corner cases?
Are there other ways to redirect besides https://www.google.com/url... ?

I found another way to redirect Here is another way to redirect: via https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&url=

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a regex

```
(?i)^(http|https)://(www.|)google.(ac|ad|aero|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|arpa|ar|asia|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|biz|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|cat|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|coop|com|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|info|int|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jobs|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mobi|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|museum|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|name|na|nc|net|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pro|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tel|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|travel|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|xn--0zwm56d|xn--11b5bs3a9aj6g|xn--80akhbyknj4f|xn--9t4b11yi5a|xn--deba0ad|xn--g6w251d|xn--hgbk6aj7f53bba|xn--hlcj6aya9esc7a|xn--jxalpdlp|xn--kgbechtv|xn--zckzah|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)/url\?.+$
```

or a readable form

```
(?i)^(http|https)://(www.|)google.(com|de)/url\?.+$
```

Lot of people considered that the question is not worth an effort of anyone. I got -4 for the question. Some questions appear to be trivial. I still hope that there is a better solution for the problem. I did not find a list of WEB sites allowing redirect of the URL like what *google.com/url\?q* does

Here is another way to redirect https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&url=

Comment: the close reasons indicate your question was not clear so it might be worth asking what isn't clear about your question. A way to reprodue the problem would have helped as well.

Comment: What is not clear about the question? There is not much to reproduce.

Comment: For me, personally, not being able to reproduce, I was unable to follow what was happening. You were making a request to an initial url and were getting two (?) redirects and wanted to be able to capture them (from where?) using regex? I didn't downvote but I did vote to close on this basis. Perhaps I should have left a comment - I apologise. I see a lot of questions in my defence and sometimes don't leave a VTC reason.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hopefully this is clearer now. The problem is tricky and not immediately obvious due to encoding.

Comment: oh...sort of.... so... you want to analyse an email you have received to work out where an url within it (the return address url?) ,  might re-direct to? And somehow you expect google to gelp you with this? Are you doing a google search on the found email url?

Comment: Given an URL I want to get the "real" URL - the one which is the redirect target

Comment: you realise you can url decode if that helps (not if it doesn't though!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199892/discussion-between-larytet-and-qharr).

Comment: and what role does Google play? To find out if it listed as a bad url somewhere on the net? Wouldn't using a service specific to this be better then? (If that is the case)